# Check the convergence of the series $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\left (n!\right )^2}{\left (2n+1\right )!}4^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to check if the following series converge or not.

- $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\left (n!\right )^2}{\left (2n+1\right )!}4^n}$

I suppose we have to find here an upper bound and apply then the comparison test. But I don’t really have an idea which bound we could take. Could you give me a hint?

- $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot \ldots \cdot (2n-1)}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot \ldots \cdot 2n}}$

We have a term that is a product of the form $\frac{2i-1}{2i}=1-\frac{1}{2i}$. To apply the comparison test we have to find an upper bound. Does it holds that $1-\frac{1}{2i}\leq \frac{1}{2}$ and so $$\prod_{i=1}^n\left (1-\frac{1}{2i}\right )\leq \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2^n}$$ Then taking the sum we get $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot \ldots \cdot (2n-1)}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot \ldots \cdot 2n}\leq \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}=1$$ So from the comparison test the original sum must converge also.

Is everything correct?

- $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot \ldots \cdot (2n-1)}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot \ldots \cdot 2n\cdot (2n+2)}}$

We have a term that is a product of the form $\frac{2i-1}{2i+2}$. Which upper bound could we use in this case?

Comment: Have you tried the ratio test?

Comment: You mean for the first series? Or for all of them? @GerryMyerson

Comment: Why don't you try it, and see?

Comment: For the 1 :$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{ \frac{\left (n!\right) ^2\cdot (n+1) ^2}{\left (2n+3\right )!}\cdot 4^{n}\cdot 4}{\frac{\left (n!\right )^2}{\left (2n+1\right )!}\cdot 4^n} =\frac{\frac{ (n+1) ^2}{\left (2n+3\right )!}\cdot 4}{\frac{1}{\left (2n+1\right )!}} =\frac{ (n+1) ^2\left (2n+1\right )!}{\left (2n+3\right )!}\cdot 4= \frac{ (n+1) ^2\left (2n+1\right )!}{\left (2n+1\right )!\cdot (2n+2)\cdot (2n+3)}\cdot 4= \frac{ (n+1) ^2}{ (2n+2)\cdot (2n+3)}\cdot 4= \frac{ (n+1) ^2}{ 2(n+1)\cdot (2n+3)}\cdot 4 = \frac{ n+1 }{  2n+3}\cdot 2= \frac{ 2n+2 }{  2n+3}\rightarrow 1$$ @GerryMyerson

Comment: Since it converges to 1 it doesn't help us, does it? @GerryMyerson

Comment: For the first one we have that $\left |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right |=\frac{2n+2}{2n+3}<1$, do we conclude from the ration test that the series converges?  Or do we have to check the limit? @GerryMyerson

Comment: Sorry, ratio test is inconclusive for first one. Still, it was worth a try.

Comment: Which test instead do you suggest here to use? @GerryMyerson

Comment: Well, how about what zkutch does in one of the answers? Does that work for you, Mary?

Comment: I will point out that all three problems are closely related, e.g., the summand in the second problem is equal to $$(2n)!\over4^n(n!)^2$$ which is practically the reciprocal of the summand in the first problem.

Comment: With regard to the third problem, Jolley, Summation of Series, quuoting Hall & Knight, Higher Algebra, gives $$\sum_1^k{(1)(3)(5)\cdots(2n-1)\over(2)(4)(6)\cdots(2n+2)}={1\over2}-{(1)(3)(5)\cdots(2n+1)\over(2)(4)(6)\cdots(2n+2)}$$

Comment: Your $1-{1\over2i}\le{1\over2}$ in the 2nd problem is wrong.

Comment: Call the summand in the 2nd problem $u_n$. Then by the Binomial Theorem, $\sum_0^{\infty}u_nx^{2n}=(1-x^2)^{-1/2}$. Since the right side is undefined at $x=1$, the sum there diverges.

Comment: My answer to the question was probably incorrect, so I deleted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some hints:

For first we can use [Raabe's](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RaabesTest.html) test
$$n\left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1 \right) = \frac{n}{2(n+1)}$$

For second
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} \leqslant \frac{1}{2} \frac{3}{4}  \cdots \frac{2n-1}{2n}  \leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}\quad (1)$$

Proof:

For $n=1$ we have $\frac{1}{2} \leqslant \frac{1}{2}  \leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $, so let's assume $n \geqslant 2$. We have
$$\frac{3}{4}>\frac{2}{3}, \frac{5}{6}>\frac{4}{5},\frac{7}{8}>\frac{6}{7}, \cdots, \frac{2n-1}{2n}>\frac{2n-2}{2n-1}$$
multiplication this inequalities gives
$$\frac{3}{4} \frac{5}{6}  \cdots \frac{2n-1}{2n} > \frac{2}{3} \frac{4}{5}  \cdots \frac{2n-2}{2n-1}$$
Now if we multiply left and right sides on left side, the we have
$$\left( \frac{3}{4} \frac{5}{6}  \cdots \frac{2n-1}{2n} \right)^2 > \frac{1}{n} $$
Which is left side of (1).

Comment: How did you get the inequality $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} \leqslant \frac{1}{2} \frac{3}{4}  \cdots \frac{2n-1}{2n}  \leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}$ ?

Comment: @Mary Star. Which side you are interesting more - left, right?

Comment: First of all, what I have done for the second series is not correct, is it? As for your question : Both... Let's start with the left side.

Comment: You mean inequality $\frac{2n-1}{2n} \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$? it is wrong already at $n=2$. As to proof of answer's inequality you should give me some time, because for some time I'll not be at comp, but then I'll write it.

Comment: @Mary Star. Added as promised. Right side needs similar steps. Write, please, if/when you'll need anything more.

Comment: Old remembers...the Raabe test :-) +1 for all answers.

Answer (score 3):

The Stirling approximation implies $\binom{2n}{n}\sim\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{n\pi}}$, so $\frac{n!^24^n}{(2n+1)!}\sim\frac{\sqrt{\pi}/2}{\sqrt{n}}$, so the series diverges.