# Pointwise and uniform convergence of power series

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I want to check the pointwise and uniform convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^ne^{-n}}{\sqrt{n}}$$

For the pointwise convergence do we check the limit of the sequence?

I mean the following: $$a_n=\frac{x^ne^{-n}}{\sqrt{n}} \rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{x^ne^{-n}}{\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{n}e^{n}}=0$$ Therefore the series converges pointwise to $0$.

Is that correct?

And for the uniform convergence do we check also the sequence?

Or do we have to do something else for the series?

Comment: It is not true that if $a_n \to 0$, then $\sum_n a_n$ converges, so your test is insufficient.

Comment: Uniform convergence mean set for $x$. Which one you have here?

Comment: It might help if you expand on what the definition of "pointwise and uniform convergence" is in this context. When one asks where a power series over $x$ converges pointwise, the question is: for which values of $x$ does it hold that the series converges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By well known [Cauchy–Hadamard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem) for power series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(z-z_0)^nc_n$ we have, that so called convergence radius $\frac{1}{R}=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sup\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}$. In our case

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{e^{-n}}{\sqrt{n}}} \to \frac{1}{e}=\frac{1}{R}$$

So we have pointwise convergence for $|x|<e$. In right border point we have divergence as for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and for left convergence $\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$.

As it is known, uniform convergence we have on each closed segment within convergence interval.

Comment: @Mary Star. By the way, I wrote for you proof which you asked about on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3797499/check-the-convergence-of-teh-series/3797531#3797531 - do you see it?

Comment: For the n-th root test we don't consider the $x^n$-term,right?

Comment: @Mary Star. Right. Link and formulation added to answer. If/when you'll have more question for this or other answers, feel free to ask.

Comment: @zkutch the ratio accepted answers / answers recently received of this user is tiny! 2 in the last 28 i.e. about 7%. (28 is what's on one page of their account). Seems to be better towards the older of their questions (36 pages!)

Comment: @Calvin Khor. Thanks. I like that name "Mary"..

Comment: Ok! And we have to check also the border points $x=R$ and $x=-R$ ?

Comment: @Mary Star. Right.

Comment: Ok, so we have pointwise convergence for $x\in \left [-e, e\right )$. You said that "uniform convergence we have on each closed segment within convergence interval". In this case we don't have a closed interval, or do you mean something else?

Comment: I mean, every $[-r,r] \subset (-e,e)$.

Comment: Is it $[-r,r] \subset (-e,e)$ or $[-r,r] \subset [-e,e)$, i.e. do we consider also $-e$ ?

Comment: First one. $[-r,r] \subset (-e,e)$. You want to achieve some concrete result?

Comment: Ah ok! Why do we not consider also the boundary where we have convergence?

Comment: It comes from general theorem. If series is converged at boundaries, then, of course it will be uniformly converged on whole closed interval.

Comment: So in thiscase do we consider $[-r,r] \subset (-e,e)$ and not $[-r,r] \subset [-e,e)$ although we have convergence at $x=-e$ because we have only at the one boundary convergence and not at both? Or am I thinking wrong?

Comment: You thinking right. This site suggest move long dialogs to separate chat. Would you like to continue in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112218/discussion-between-mary-star-and-zkutch).

Comment: Thank you for your help!! :-)